# After creating a bigger array, how do I use the new array in other functions of the same class?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-arrays

It was asked of us to implement this class without built-in functions or Arraylist.
When needing to make the data array bigger, I created a new array and gave it a new size (which is the capacity+10). As the data array is a data member, I can access it from the other functions of the array. However, I can't access the newArray. Can I create a bigger array using the data array? If not,how can I access the new Array from the other functions of the class?

```
package ADTDynamicArrays;
import java.util.*;


public class DynamicIntgerArray {

    public int data[];
    int size;
    int capacity;

public DynamicIntgerArray(){

    data = new int[5];
    size = 0; 
    capacity = 5;

}

public DynamicIntgerArray(int ca){
        size=0;
        if(ca<5)
            capacity=5;
        else
            capacity=ca;
        data=new int[capacity];
    }

public boolean checkIndex(int index){
  if(index < 0 || index >=data.length)
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: " + index + ",        Size: " + size); 
    else
        return true; }

public void copyOldtoNew(int [] arry1, int arry2[]){
        arry2=arry1;
                      }

public void checkCapacity(int s){
    if(capacity<= s){
        capacity +=10 ;
                    int newArray[]=new int[capacity];
                    copyOldtoNew(data,newArray);
                                    }
    }

    public void getElement (int index){

    }

    public int getlength(){
        return capacity;
                           }

public void insertElement(int element){

                               }

public void replaceElement(int index, int element){

                              }
public void print(){



                                 }



public void addShiftElements(int index, int element){

}
}
```

This is the code that was given to us that we have to work with that we cannot modify:

```
package ADTDynamicArrays;
import java.util.*;
public class DynamicIntgerArray {

public int [] data;





public DynamicIntgerArray(){
    data = new int[5];
    size = 0; 
    capacity = 5;}


public DynamicIntgerArray(int ca){




                                 }

public boolean checkIndex(int index){
  if(index < 0 || index >=data.length)
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: " + index + ",        Size: " + size); 
    else
        return true; }

public void copyOldtoNew(int [] arry1, int arry2[]){


                      }

public void checkCapacity(int s){
    if(capacity<= s){
        capacity +=10 ;


                         }
        }

public void getElement (int index){


                              }

public int getlength(){

                           }

public void insetElement(int element){
        checkCapacity(size+1);


                               }

public void replaceElement(int index, int element){



                              }


public void print(){



                                 }



public void addShiftElements(int index, int element){
    if(checkIndex(index)){
        checkCapacity(size + 1);






    }        

}

}
```

Comment: I assume there is code you may/can not modify? What part do you need to write? And wich parts may not be modified? Further more, if this is a school task please keep in mind that SO is not meant  to solve your homework problems!

Comment: I added the code that isn't meant to be modified. It is an old problem that I dug up. No problems here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to create a new array and then reference data array to it like this way

int oldItems[] = new int[10];// this is your data array

int newItems[] = new int[20];// this is new array created

System.arraycopy(oldItems, 0, newItems, 0, 10);// copy new array to data array

oldItems = newItems;// your data saved and size increased of data array

Answer (score 2):

After this code:

```
int newArray[]=new int[capacity];
copyOldtoNew(data,newArray);
```

you need this little piece of magic:

```
data = newArray;
```

<sub>well, I hope you understand it is not magic at all.</sub>

Comment: Yes, but the sizes of the 2 arrays are different. Isn't this statement only going to copy the elements?

Comment: No, this statement is not going to copy the elements.  `data` is just a pointer to the block of memory holding your array.  `newArray` is another pointer to another block.  The statement `data = newArray;` replaces one pointer with the other.  The old block is not referenced anymore, so it will be garbage-collected.  This pointer copy is very fast, and it will work.

Comment: So the pointer called data will be assigned to the new array?

Comment: No, the pointer called `newArray` will be assigned to the pointer called `data`.

Comment: Ok, it is very clear thank you. I was misleaded by the fact that it is always said that pointers aren't used in Java.